# Unity GameObject rotating around global axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm starting to create my first game on unity in 3D and for this I'm consulting many tutorials but I haven't found an answer to my question.
I created a script that rotates the main camera when moving the mouse.
But the character does not rotate on itself but seems to rotate around an axis external to his body
How can I do? Thanks a lot for the replies.

Here the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class visual : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    float sensibility = 100f;
    float rotation;

    void Start ()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * sensibility;
        float y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * sensibility;

        rotation -= y;
        rotation = Mathf.Clamp(rotation, -60f, 60f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation, 0, 0); 

        player.Rotate(Vector3.up * x);
    }
}
```

I tried to search a right code but I didn't find any working code.

Comment: If that is the case then you should checkout the pivot point of your model .. it seems to have an offset

Comment: Your title should be more descriptive of what is in the question. For example: “Unity GameObject rotating around global axis”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the setup of you `player` object this is more a guess:
Check the player object whether the visuals are not in a child with an offset for example. Or as derHugo mentioned the offset could be wrong.

Alternatively you might wanna check on **[Spaces](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Space.html)**. By default when you call `transform.Rotate` Space is set to `Space.Self` but maybe switching it to `Space.World` and then see what happens could at least give you a further hint.

---

Update after looking into linked code:

The orange markes object has the script that rotates with the camera. The yellow marked objects (`Main Camera` and `Player`) must be centered within the `player` object.

How to solve this?
Set the `Transform->Position` for `Main Camera` and `Player` to `0,0,0`. Then adjust the ONLY height (so `y`) of the `Main Camera` and `Player`.

[image]

Comment: yes, the camera is together with the character model in a container. I tried to put the camera out of the container but in this way the camera remained stationary and the character always turned but not on itself.

Comment: Could you maybe push the code to github and share it? Would be easier to figure out by looking at the setup.

Comment: I post the unity project here because is larger than 100mb. In this way you can import the project in unity and check it. (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aegjoJVRE802BrjlaIME-egVW1yqdXqg?usp=share_link). Ty

Comment: Yes it was a transform offset in the children of the rotating object. I updated my answer with a screenshot and detailed steps on how to solve this.

Comment: And please adjust the title of this question as SupaMaggie70 suggested in a comment above :)